# Magento 2.1.9 - Provided attribute can not be used with configurable product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute

1. Created custom product attribute set **Bag Size** based on Default
   attribute set
2. Created custom attribute bag_size and added 4 custom swatches i.e.
   bag sizes
3. Created 4 simple products with different size and assigned to
   created attribute set
4. Created configurable product and under Configuration added those
   simple products manually

Getting below error and unable to create configurable product.

[image]

Following the same process of creating configurable product where simple products are created and assigned to one configurable product.

Attribute Properties

[image]

Attribute Advanced Properties

[image]

Comment: I think an attribute needs some properties, so that it can be used for a configurable product (e.g. global scope). Please add a screenshot of your attribute properties.

Answer (score 1):

So that an attribute can be used for configurable products, it has to have the following properties:

- scope is set to global
- attribute is visible
- attribute is user defined
- attribute uses a source (which is e.g. the case for dropdown and multiselect attributes)

See `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::canUseAttribute`.

Comment: Properties screenshot updated under Attribute Advanced Properties. Am I still missing something ? I have tried creating a configurable product and add configuration. Still it is not creating any product. Also it throws exception while saving new configurable product - Attribute with attributeCode "156" does not exist.

Comment: @Vikram you cannot use "Text Swatch" for "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner". You have to set it to "Drodown".

Comment: Could you please explain why dropdown instead of Text Swatch ? Also by changing Catalog Input Type for Store Owner to Dropdown, it says `Attribute with attributeCode "X" does not exist.`

Comment: @Vikram I cannot explain why text swatch does not work. I can only say that Magento blocks other input types. You have to use "Dropdown". See the mentioned method. The other error message is another question.

Answer (score 1):

this is the good code to create a product attribute that can be used for configurable product tested on Magento 2.3.

The required parameters are :

```
'source'=> \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class
'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'user_defined' => true,
'visible' => true,
```

complete code

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'size',
        [
            'group' => 'Erp',
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Taille',
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 20,
            'position'=> 0,
            'source'=> \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table::class,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'is_used_in_grid' => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false
        ]
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have to add around 3000 attribute values. For that reason I created attribute and its options progrmmatically. When I try to use this attributes in product level it was giving trouble.

I had the same problem when I try to edit the product. After some short of experiment, **I created attribute manually and added its options progrmmatically** that solved my problem. And ensure the scope of attribute to **Global**, Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront to **Yes**.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Simon's answer:

1. Text Swatches can be used for creating configurable products. If you're adding the attribute programmatically, just make sure you use

> Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table

as **source_model**.

2. Also, if you're adding the attribute programmatically, make sure you don't add any value to the field "apply_to" (found in catalog_eav_attribute). Don't know why, didn't bother to find out.

Answer (score 0):

In case where your get this error because attribute have been added programmatically and

$attribute->getIsUserDefined() equal false mean it's a system attribut then

you can run sql query :

```
UPDATE `dpx_eav_attribute` SET `is_user_defined` = '1' WHERE `dpx_eav_attribute`.`attribute_code` = "{your attribut code}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just been debugging this since the above did not help. Found another issue in the following file:
`\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ConfigurableAttributeHandler::isAttributeApplicable`

We had this issue with migrated attributes from m1. The method above checks if attribute `apply_to` is empty or exactly matches

```
$types = [
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL,
            \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE,
        ];
```

This was not the case for us. So, cases where attribute `apply_to` is set to `simple,configurable` for example won't show up in the configurable wizard.